# What type of lock is acquiring delete..using statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I’m developing system for booking and in some cases it is important to have good performance.

I wan’t to regularly execute in my Postgres database something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM table t1 
USING  table t2 
WHERE t1.updated < t2.updated 
AND t1.attr = t2.attr
```

I know that Postgres provides various lock modes to control concurrent access to data and some of them are automatically used while query executing.

In official documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) noticed that `DELETE` and another modification statements acquire the `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock mode, but is there some extra-limitations due to `USING`?

Would it be more optimal to split query into 2 statements and execute them consistently?

I've been trying to test both ways, but I didn't find any significant differences.

What should I do to make application performance better?

Comment: always start with a query plan, `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement. The DDL for all tables and indexes involved, is also needed. And how many records (in both tables) do you expect? How many times per hour/day/month are you going to execute this query? Is there even a need to execute the query? (We never delete records, just drop entire partitions)

Answer (score 1):

You can figure tat out very easily with an experiment:

```
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM uni u1
USING uni u2
WHERE u1.id = u2.id;

-- get all the table locks on "uni" by the current session
SELECT mode
FROM pg_locks
WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid()
  AND relation = 'uni'::regclass;

       mode       
══════════════════
 AccessShareLock
 RowExclusiveLock
(2 rows)
```

There is a `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on `u1` and an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on `u2`. The latter is unnecessary, because it is the same table, and the former lock is stronger than the latter, but it wouldn't pay to try and optimize that.